# react-testing-library check founded element tag

Tags: reactjs, testing, react-testing-library

I want to compare founded element's tag. Which query should i use?

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**App.test.js**

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('is hello world inside the h1 tag', () => {
  render(<App />);
  const titleElement = screen.getByText(/Hello world/i);
  /* I want to check titleElement as h1 tag */
  expect(titleElement)...
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to test for the <form> tag. It doesn't have text. Any ideas on how to test for a tag without text?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution like this

```
expect(titleElement.tagName.toLowerCase()).toBe("h1")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it into a one-liner using React Testing library API:

```
expect(getByRole('heading', { level: 1, name: '/Hello world/i' })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is another approach. But in my question I try compare tag name of found element.